Can a Nidah do Kedushin?
Would a man giving a nidah a ring be an issue, since usually a husband can't hand their wife something when they are nidah?
Also, would both of them being isolated for nisuin be an issue?

They are not husband and wife until AFTER she gets the ring, so handing to her would not be an issue.

The husband may put the ring on her finger if he does so without touching her skin, but some Rabbis might ask him to just put it in her hand.
After this all normal laws of Niddah are followed.
Yichud would not be allowed. There are discrete ways of handling this. One should speak to one's Rabbi.
There are other relevant details. All is discussed on this Yoatzot page.
There are ways of planning, or hormonal treatment options that many use to prevent this in the first place.

Just FYI, my impression from various premarital materials is that pre-wedding hormonal treatment isn't quite as popular as it was 20 years ago, and Rabbi J David Bleich shlit'a describes it as "something that a lot of people do, though I don't see why."

@Shalom avoiding embarrassing the kallah comes to mind. What is the context of this teshuva?

It was a parenthetical in his lecture to semicha students about doing weddings. He also said that to visibly change any part of the proceeding (e.g. drop the ring into the palm) would be embarrassing, and therefore everything should be done the same way. (Except Yichud, of course, but almost nobody finds out about that.)

@Shalom in weddings where there is a Mitzvah Tantz, there's another obvious difference, where the chosson would not be able to hold the kallah's hand. I've heard that hormonal treatments before the wedding are much more ubiquitous in Chassidish communities for this reason. Also because those communities often plan weddings much farther in advance, which makes avoiding the situation with planning basically impossible.
